# Can't Have 2 list items appear on the same line

Tags: html, css

When I put 2 `li` tags I can't have them appear on the same line when you look at my website. What can I do?

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet so that we have more information to help you?

Comment: Use CSS and apply `display: inline-block;` to them. In the future, familiarize yourself with how to ask questions. Not only has this question been asked plenty of times, questions require you to include code. Voting to close.

Comment: off the top of my head `display: block` should do it

Comment: I'm inclined to suggest you visit zombo.com. What is the problem here? Do you want these tags to appear on the same line or not? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tenCupMaximum `display: block;` will do the exact opposite of what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Santi Doesn't OP say he *doesn't* want them on the same line? [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=block)

Comment: I've just noticed, and as @squeamishossifrage suggests, it seems the wording is ambiguous...

Comment: @tenCupMaximum Yeah I suppose the wording is ambiguous, though the default display of `li` is `list-item`, which is a block-type display. So, in other words, `<li>`'s are essentially `display: block;` by default. Regardless, the question should be closed.

Comment: @Santi that's a good point, although I was assuming he had existing CSS or some other condition. Not that I thought too hard about it before commenting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS declaration "display: inline".

Comment: You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have two lists:

1. Name the lists by **class**, this case: *list-1* and *list-2*

   ```
   //HTML
   <ul class="list-1">
     <li>Here</li>
     <li>There</li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="list-2">
     <li>Sand</li>
     <li>Rope</li>
   </ul>
   ```

---

2. In the css part, declare **display: inline-block**

   ```
   //CSS
   .list-1, .list-2
   {
      display: inline-block;
   }
   ```